# Probability drawn card does not match turn number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, card-games

We play a game with a (shuffled) standard 52 poker cards deck where each card value is in  $\{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K\}$. For simplicity, relabel the 13 values as $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0\}$. The game requires each turn to not flip the card with the turn's number as value. Formally:

**Game rules**:

i. At each turn $n\ge 1$ we flip a card.

ii. If at turn $n$ we flip $n$ mod $13$ we lose, otherwise we move on to turn $n+1$.

iii. We win if we reach turn $n=52$ (i.e. we flip all cards in the deck) and the last card is not a $0$ (i.e. a $K$).

**Question**: What is the probability of winning?

(Comment: actually I am struggling with the same game with, say, a deck  of 10 cards with values $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0\}$. I tried to calculate the number of deck's permutations such that the $i$-th position does not contain value $i$, but I can't find a simple way to count this.)

Comment: This is not a simple problem. See the [Wikipedia article on derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for help on the simplified problem in your final paragraph; the full 52-card problem will be more complicated.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: this type of permuation is called a 'derangement'. The wikipedia page might have some interesting information:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: O... I see TonyK just typed the same thing at the same time...

Comment: As others have pointed out, this problem is a more complicated version of a derangement.  Problems involving derangements are usually solved by the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  For this more complicated version, one might use an extension of inclusion/exclusion: a [rook polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial).